# Calculating electrostatic potential from arbitrary charge density

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

In electrostatics, one often desires to know the electrostatic potential generated from the outside of a charge distribution; however, I am interested in finding the electrostatic potential *inside* of a charge distribution.

For example, let's consider a parabolic charge distribution: $\rho(x) = x(L-x)$
Where L is the length of the distribution.
Now if we wish to calculate the electrostatic potential, we would need to calculate:

$\Phi(z) = \int_0^L \frac{\rho(x)}{|z-x|} dx = \int_0^L \frac{x(L-x)}{|z-x|} dx$

In turn one could take the derivative of $\Phi(z)$ to obtain the electric field inside the distribution.

My attempt to do this in mathematica:

```
L = 1;
s[z_] := z (L-z)
fen[x_] := Integrate[s[z]/Abs[z - x], {z, 0, L}, PrincipalValue -> True, Assumptions :> {L > x > 0}]
V = fen[x]
El = fen'[x]
Plot[{V, El}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: This does not gives us much to work with to be honest. What have you tried? Give examples of your distribution etc.

Comment: For any distribution, i.e. ellipse: $\rho(x) = x(1-x)$
I've tried using Principal Value to no avail also.

Comment: [Everything you ever wanted to do with _Mathematica_ and electrostatic potentials... and more!](http://blog.wolfram.com/2012/07/20/on-the-importance-of-being-edgy-electrostatic-and-magnetostatic-problems-with-sharp-edges/) (follow the links to parts 2 & 3)

Comment: @StarStrides Your question is not very clear.  Please edit the original post (not just comment) and rephrase it a bit: in particular show us a *short* example illustrating what you have tried and what went wrong.  By example I mean Mathematica code with explanation.

Comment: Why are you using this potential? For 1 dimension, the potential is linear (if we talk about standard Coulomb potential - yes, 1D has a confinement), for 2D it is logarithmic, and only for 3D it is `1/r`. So, either you have to change the formula, or add integration volume for 2D and 3D.

Comment: I've updated the question, I hope it is more clear.  @LeonidShifrin - I am interested in simplifying the 3D problem to 1D for now.  Thanks.

Comment: For arbitrary charge density in 2D, you may also want to have a look at: [Poisson solver using Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11763/245)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surely you can do it for any charge distribution as it is just evaluating integrals!

However, I have to point out a severe problem in what you are going to calculate. What I am going to say may not be an answer to your question. (I would like to make this a comment but I dont have enough reputation to do so.)

Your charge distribution is 1-dimensional,
$$ \rho(x) = x(L-x).  $$

The problem is, you are using a 3-D green function $\frac{1}{|\vec{x}-\vec{x}'|}$ of the 3-D Laplacian $\nabla^2$ to calculate a 1-D problem. The correct result is not showing up for sure.

Instead you should use the 1-D green function $ \frac{1}{2}|x-x'|$ for the potential, i.e.

$$ \Phi(x)  = \int_0^L\frac{1}{2}|x-x'|\rho(x') dx' $$

Comment: First, thank you for understanding that I did not understand @LeonidShifrin comment/answer in my original question's comment.  Second, it is to my surprise that I have not covered this (or perhaps forgotten) that these Green's function's are dimension-dependent.  
Lastly for discussion, I am somewhat disturbed by the implication that it is only in 3D, that the force between two charged particles scales as 1/r^2.  Many thanks, my simulations make much more sense now :)!