# Poisson PDE in a rectangular domain

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, finite-difference-method

I found a solution for this problem, but this is in Scilab and I never use Scilab. Can anyone can help me to translate it in *Mathematica*?
Here is the Link:http://imechanica.org/files/TorqueR.pdf

I solved this problem with `NDSolve` but now I want to implement it with FDM, like this.

```
Clear[a, b, n, m, Δx, Δy, G, θ, 
  sol, vars, ϕsol, eqns, tauyz, tauxz, ϕ, gammaxz, gammayz]
a = 0.04;
b = 0.04;
n = 5;
m = 5;
Δx = a/n;
Δy = b/m;
G = 13.125 10^6;
θ = 0.002;
ϕ[0, j_] = 0;
ϕ[n, j_] = 0;
ϕ[i_, 0] = 0;
ϕ[i_, m] = 0;
Ψ[i_, j_] = -2 G θ;
vars = Flatten[Table[ϕ[i, j], {i, 1, n - 1}, {j, 1, m - 1}]];
eqns = 
  Flatten[
    Table[
      (ϕ[i + 1, j] - 2 ϕ[i, j] + ϕ[i - 1, j])/Δx^2 + 
      (ϕ[i, j + 1] - 2 ϕ[i, j] + ϕ[i, j - 1])/Δy^2 == Ψ[i, j], 
      {i, 1, n - 1}, {j, 1, m - 1}]];
sol = Solve[eqns, vars][[1]];
ϕsol = 
  Interpolation[
    Flatten[Table[{i Δx, j Δy, ϕ[i, j]}, {i, 0, n}, {j, 0, m}] /. sol, 1]];
tauyz = -D[ϕsol[x, y], x];
tauxz = D[ϕsol[x, y], y];
gammayz = tauyz/G;
gammaxz = tauxz/G;
```

but this only works for a rectangle, but I need to solve for a rectangle with hole in the center, like this:

[image]

Comment: According to the link, the program is written with [SciLab](http://www.scilab.org/)

Comment: if you want Poisson solver using FDM on rectangular cross section, there is a demo that implements this with many other solvers as well. http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SolvingThe2DPoissonPDEByEightDifferentMethods/

Comment: @Nasser Thank, yes I saw that but I need to solve on rectangular with hole

Comment: If there is a hole inside the section, then it is not rectangular section any more. FDM is hard to use when there is circular or any other shape boundaries since the meshing becomes hard to get correct (some points end up outside and some inside, etc..).That is why I think FEM would be easier for this. But you really need to describe the geometry better. What are the dimensions? What is the hole shape? etc..

Comment: Ok,  but when inside the rectangle is another smaller rectangle?

Comment: When the hole is also rectangular shape, then makes it easier, since the grid can be made to align there. with the rest of the region with no problem. So all what you have to do, is in the loop as you scan the region (updating the solution at each point), is simply check if you are inside the hole or not.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what your actual *Mathematica* question is.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/59441/57

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries yes that's what I want to solve with FDM

Comment: @Jens my question is that how can I transform this existing program to calculate/solve the rectangle with a hole inside?

Comment: Then I would say (again) that this is a duplicate of [Poisson solver using Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11763/245), because your problem is a special case of that one.

Comment: I'd say just use the program I linked to, change the Laplace equation to the poisson equation, and update the boundary condition.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I would definitely agree, but in an earlier question it seemed that the OP has a version of Mathematica in which FEM was still buggy, so he needs a finite-difference type solution.

Comment: @jens Ah, I see. But from reading that question it seems he has 10.0.0 which can be freely updated to 10.0.2

Comment: @Nasser I would like it for any geometry,I mean am trying to do it. I want to illustrate difference between thin walled structures and thick walled structures

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I updated yesterday but i want solve with FDM

Comment: "I would like it for any geometry" - 如果这就是你的终级目标的话，那么，我在你的第一个问题里给出的代码本来就是适用于任何二维直角坐标系下的泊松方程的，你只需要把开头用于指定区域的部分稍微改改就行——‌​‌​你要是看不懂我的答案那你完全可以在下面追问。Translation: If this is your ultimate goal, then the code in my answer for your first question is completely suited for the task, you just need to modify the part defining the region i.e. `rulei` and `ruleo`. If you have any difficulty in understanding, feel free to continue to ask in the comment under my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very simple way to do it. I modified your code very little to add the condition, that is inside a hole, then set the solution to be the boundary condition at the edge of the hole inside, which I set to be zero.

Added one line:

```
  startRow = 4; endRow = 6; startCol = 4; endCol = 6;
```

Which tells the boundaries of the hole. And inside the `Table` added an `If` to check:

```
If[i >= startRow && i <= endRow && j >= startCol && j <= endCol,
 ϕ[i, j] == 0,
 .... same as before
 ],
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

With more mesh, the solution should become better.

Here is your code with the small modification

```
Clear[a, b, n, m, Δx, Δy, G, θ, sol, vars, ϕsol, eqns, tauyz, tauxz, ϕ, gammaxz, \
gammayz]
a = 0.04;
b = 0.04;
n = 100;
m = 100;
Δx = a/n;
Δy = b/m;
G = 13.125 10^6;
θ = 0.002;
ϕ[0, j_] = 0;
ϕ[n, j_] = 0;
ϕ[i_, 0] = 0;
ϕ[i_, m] = 0;
Ψ[i_, j_] = -2 G θ;
startRow = 40; endRow = 60; startCol = 40; endCol = 60;
vars = Flatten[Table[ϕ[i, j], {i, 1, n - 1}, {j, 1, m - 1}]];

eqns = Table[
   If[i >= startRow && i <= endRow && j >= startCol && j <= endCol,
    ϕ[i, j] == 0, (*assume B.C. in hole edge is zero *)
    (ϕ[i + 1, j] - 2 ϕ[i, j] + ϕ[i - 1, j])/Δx^2 + (ϕ[i, j + 1] - 
         2 ϕ[i, j] + ϕ[i, j - 1])/Δy^2 == Ψ[i, j]
    ],
   {i, 1, n - 1}, {j, 1, m - 1}
   ];

sol = Solve[Flatten@eqns, vars][[1]];

ϕsol = Interpolation[Flatten[Table[{i Δx, j Δy, ϕ[i, j]}, {i, 0, n}, {j, 0, m}] /. sol, 1]];
tauyz = -D[ϕsol[x, y], x];
tauxz = D[ϕsol[x, y], y];
gammayz = tauyz/G;
gammaxz = tauxz/G;
```